# Using "Whenever" in German sentences

Tags: vocabulary

I'm very stuck on how to express the idea of "whenever" in German sentences.

Take the example, "You can come round whenever suits you best", which I just wanted to say to my landlord about repairing something.

How best do I say this? I was stuck for ages because I couldn't work out if it was supposed to be "wann auch immer" or if it could just be "wann immer"?

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Would you say, that *whenever* is really an important addition as opposed to *when* in English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*whenever* translates to several expressions in German:

One is relating to the frequency of doing something like in "Come areound whenever (as often as) you like", this would translate into

> Komm' vorbei sooft du magst.

The other one relates to "any time" and is a nearly literal one

> Komm' vorbei wann (auch) immer du magst.

Or, simply leave out the "ever" - it doesn't carry a lot of meaning (like it does in English) and say

> Komm' vorbei wann du magst.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase *wann auch immer* isn't really used much in German. [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wann%20auch%20immer%2Cwann%20immer&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwann%20auch%20immer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwann%20immer%3B%2Cc0) tells us that it is comparatively rare in books:

[image: Google Ngrams of "wann auch immer,wann immer"]

To me the phrase *wann auch immer* carries a connotation of disinterest:

> *Sie können kommen, wann immer sie wollen.* "Whenever you want to come is perfectly fine with me."
> *Sie können kommen, wann auch immer sie wollen, ich werde sie nicht hereinlassen.* "I don't give a wet fart about when you want to come, you'll not get in."